# history function for bootstrap navbar and jquery load-function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, browser-history

I am new to this area. 
I build a navbar with bootstrap 3 and the "load"-function. If I want to use the back button of the browser, it does not work. 
What do I have to do to make it work?

Here my simplified code:

index.html:

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top text-center">
     <div class="container">
         <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
             <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="#" onclick="$('#main').load('files/link1.html');  return false;">Link1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" onclick="$('#main').load('files/link2.html');  return false;">Link2</a></li>
             </ul>
         </div>
     </div>
 </nav>
```

Thanks Schulz

Comment: What does `If I want to use the back button of the browser, it does not work` mean? Please try to be more specific - what are you expecting to happen when you click the back button - if you want the browser to remember the history of what you're doing then you have to tell it - search on here for "manually adding to history"

Comment: What I mean, I press Link1 first, then Link2. The contents of Link2 are displayed. Then I press the back button of the browser. Now the content of Link1 should be loaded and displayed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy way to do this. You would have to use the [history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) object and change the URL every time you click on something that you want to come back to later.

Basically *on click* you don't only load the remote content but also update the URL. You would also have to use a hash (#) in URL so the page won't refresh. This implies creating a *routing* mechanism for your app.